# Get an image from gallery Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gallery

I am trying to create an app in Android Studio that allows a user to choose a picture from their gallery. My code so far is:

```
public void openGallery ()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    // Show only images, no videos or anything else
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    // Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            // Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.chosenImage);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This does not work. When I run the app and click the button to choose an image it causes the app to crash. There is no error message. Is there something wrong with my code?

**Logcat**

```
07-25 18:48:29.590 4892-4892/com.example.findmyitem E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.findmyitem, PID: 4892
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method openGallery(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton with id 'galleryButton'
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:424)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:381)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6897)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26101)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: Eager to see Your Logcat when your app crash, please paste that too.

Comment: Have you granted run time `READ and WRITE EXTERNAL STORAGE` permission?

Comment: @MohammedFarhan I had only granted `READ` not `WRITE` but it still does not work after adding it.

Comment: Change `openGallery ()` method signature to `openGallery (View v)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is saying that it cannot find method `openGallery(View )` and you have just `openGallery()` without `View` parameters inside it. Since you are referring that method in XML you should change that method signature to `openGallery(View v)`